# Mongoose pre/post middleware not getting called for model.save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I looked at the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) and can't figure out the problem. The pre & post middleware doesn't seem to be working. I have updated node and all of my modules.

```
// schema.js
const schema = mongoose.Schema(...)

schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    console.log('pre save') // I don't see this in the console
    next()
})
schema.post('save', function(next) {
    console.log('post save') // I don't see this in the console
    next()
})

module.exports = ({
    MySchema: mongoose.model('MySchema', schema)
})


// api.js
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const model = new MySchema(...)
    model.save().then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(201)
    })
}
```

Comment: Are there errors in `.save`? Add `.catch(console.error)`

Comment: No, there aren't errors in `.save`.

Comment: @Rob Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I took a break from it and eventually found my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't filling all of the `required` fields, and I was going planning on doing so in the `pre.save` middleware function. I was getting an error "Path `fieldName` is required" but there was no stack trace, so I didn't know that the issue was with the `validate` middleware. I assumed the error was happening during the `save` method.

TL;DR: The methods in order are init, validate, and save. [See Save/Validate Hooks in the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order).